# 'type' object is not iterable with Django Rest Framework and django oauth2-toolkit

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-oauth

Well I am trying to create new access token for the login user on creation with custom authentication class in views.

Serializer.py

```
class UserCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):            

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(validated_data['username'], 
            validated_data['email'],
            validated_data['password'])
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email' ,'password')
```

views.py

```
class User_Create_view(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserCreateSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    authentication_classes = Has_Access_Token

    def create(self, request):
        serializers =self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializers.is_valid():
        # pdb.set_trace()
            serializers.save()   
            # Has_Access_Token.access_token(Has_Access_Token())         
            return Response(serializers.data)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED))
```

permission.py

```
class Has_Access_Token(BaseAuthentication):
    def access_token(self):
        app = Application.objects.get(name="testing")
        tok = generate_token()
        pdb.set_trace()
        acce_token=AccessToken.objects.get_or_create(
        user=User.objects.all().last(),
        application=app,
        expires=datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=365),
        token=tok)
        return acce_token

    @method_decorator(access_token)
    def authenticate(self):
        return request
```

If I use the Decorator

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 33, in update_wrapper
    setattr(wrapper, attr, getattr(wrapped, attr))
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '**module**'

If I am Not using the Decorator
  File "/home/allwin/Desktop/response/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 262, in get_authenticators
    return [auth() for auth in self.authentication_classes]
    TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

The Problem I am facing is that when i use the Has_Access_Token fuction implicitly after serializer.save() Access token is generated in admin with respect to user but that's not effective method, so I need to override the custom authentication_class in views.

Could somebody please suggest some ways to tackle this issue or perhaps let me know the decorator correction with the above code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

While setting `REST_FRAMEWORK.DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` in `settings.py` file, the `customAuthencationClass` must like below:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [ # need to be list not tuple
        'CustomAuthentication',
    ],
}
```